# Select characters in Visual mode (works differently than Normal mode)

Tags: visual-mode, cursor-motions

I'm trying to understand the difference in character counting between Normal and Visual modes.

```
Roses are red,
Violets are blue,
Sugar is sweet,
And so are you.
```

The task is to copy everything from `are` on the 1st line to `so` on the last:

```
are red,
Violets are blue,
Sugar is sweet,
And so
```

In Normal mode it could be achieved with `wy13w`. However, when I use the same command in Visual mode (`wv13w`), the selection looks wrong:

[image]

What's wrong with it?

---

temporary image (see comments):

[image]

Comment: Do `set selection=exclusive` and try again. Now after `wv13w` the cursor is still on the `a`, but when you yank the visual area, the `a` is not included. See help for `selection` and for `visual-mode`. I don't know why it is that way.

Comment: @Ralf Thanks, it works. However, `a` is not selected at all (I added temporary image). Also, does `set selection=exclusive` have any pitfalls?

Comment: John, I don't know it exactly. Let's hope, that someone knows more and provides an answer.

Comment: it's because `w` by default is an **exclusive** motion, however when using a default selection, it will be changed to an **inclusive** motion. This can be controlled by the `'selection'` option as mentioned